# Curl and oAuth2

Tags: json, bash, nginx, curl, oauth-2.0

Hello guys I use oAuth2 from google to let my coworkers to access the office via OpenVPN, heres the auth metod:

code=*)
    CODE=${QUERY_STRING:5}
    ACCESS_JSON=`curl -sd "client_id=$CLIENT_ID&client_secret=$CLIENT_SECRET&code=$CODE&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=https://???????/cgi-bin/oauth.sh" https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token`
    # json_get_var REFRESH_TOKEN "refresh_token"
    REFRESH_TOKEN=`echo $ACCESS_JSON |  cut -d, -f4 |grep refresh_token | cut -d'"' -f4`
    echo "Content-type: text/html"
*)

So  we auth with google accounts, a token is generated and gets  access to the network via OpenVPN. But my problem is that I cannot control the users as who can log even if they have google account. I want a restrict the access with whitelist in which I put accounts that can access and everyone else should be dropped. Am new to bash, curl and etc am not a scripting guy. P.S this is on nginx. So it will be really helpful if anyone can give any tips.

Answer (score 0):

code=*) CODE=${QUERY_STRING:11} ACCESS_JSON=curl -sd "client_id=$CLIENT_ID&client_secret=$CLIENT_SECRET&code=$CODE&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=https://???????/cgi-bin/oauth.sh" https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token # json_get_var REFRESH_TOKEN "access_json" REFRESH_TOKEN= $ACCESS_JSON | in-d,